# Is Noah's curse of Canaan a prophecy the LORD would become, or take on the form of a servant?

Tags: genesis

As a result of Ham's actions, Noah pronounced a curse on his grandson, Ham's fourth son:

> When Noah awoke from his wine and knew what his youngest son had done to him, he said, “Cursed be Canaan; a servant of servants shall he be to his brothers.”
> (Genesis 9:24-25) [ESV]

Noah continues to speak prophetically about his sons Shem and Japheth and Canaan:

> He also said, “Blessed be the LORD, the God of Shem;
> and let Canaan be his servant. May God enlarge Japheth,
> and let him dwell in the tents of Shem,
> and let Canaan be his servant.” (Genesis 9:26-27)

It seems when speaking of Shem, Noah is also saying Canaan will be a servant to the LORD, the God of Shem. In other words, Canaan will not only be a servant to his "brothers" Shem and Japheth, he will be a servant to the LORD, who is Shem's God. Looking to the future, Christ Jesus takes on the form of a servant ([Philippians 2:5-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%202%3A5-8&version=ESV)) and so that sense "a servant of servants" would include the LORD, the God of Shem.

Is Noah's curse on Canaan a prophecy the LORD would become, or take on the form of a servant?

Related question: [who are the other “Servants” that Noah was referring to in Gen 9:25?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30518/canaan-is-the-servant-but-who-are-the-other-servants-that-noah-was-referring)?

Comment: I cannot see that such a curse would be an allusion to the filial humility (to the Father) of the coming Lord.

Comment: @NigelJ It is not the curse which does this, rather the blessing of the LORD, the God of Shem, whom Canaan will [also] serve.

Answer (score 1):

The curse and prophecy of Gen 9:25-27 contains three statements about Canaan (apparently a metaphoric reference to Ham):

- (v25) a servant of servant to his brothers
- (V26) a servant to Shem
- (V27) a servant to Shem

The name of the LORD is used to amplify the blessing on Shem (v26).  However, nothing here is either a reference to the coming Messiah, nor the characteristics of Messiah.  The prophecy is purely about the future relationship of the three brothers (actually their descendants); specifically, that Canaan would be a servant to Shem.

Note the weighty instruction in 1 Cor 4:6 -

> learn from us the meaning of the saying, "Do not go beyond what is
> written."

Answer (score 1):

```
Is Noah's curse on Canaan a prophecy
the LORD would become, or take on the
form of a servant?
```

I hate assuming, but, it seems to me the question *might* be based on the premise that Jesus is descended from Ham.
This is clearly not the case, Jesus being plainly descended from Shem.

> This is the account of Shem’s family line.
>
> Genesis 11:10 NIV

Through the end of that chapter clearly describing Abraham's descent from Shem.

> This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, **the son of Abraham** ...
>
> Matthew 1:1 NIV

Again through the rest of that chapter describing in detail that descent.

> Thus there were fourteen generations in all from Abraham to David, fourteen from David to the exile to Babylon, and fourteen from the exile to the Messiah.
>
> Matthew 1:17 NIV

Or by Joseph :

> Now Jesus himself ... was the son, so it was thought, of Joseph ...
>
> ... the son of Shem ...
>
> Luke 3:23,36 NIV

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_people

So no. The curse on Canaan doesn't bear directly.

Regardless, being a servant to all was part of the mandate.
Making an offering for sin, an acceptable offering, meant sacrifice.

> Day after day every priest stands and performs his religious duties; again and again he offers the same sacrifices, which can never take away sins.
>
> But when this priest had offered for all time one sacrifice for sins, he sat down at the right hand of God ...
>
> Hebrews 10:11-12 NIV

The mission of the messiah is to offer himself for everyone, including Canaan.

> Very rarely will anyone die for a righteous person, though for a good person someone might possibly dare to die.
>
> But God demonstrates his own love for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died for us.
>
> Romans 5:7-8 NIV

Answer (score 0):

In Luke 12, Jesus teaches that faithful servants are blessed, not cursed.

> 41Peter said, “Lord, are you telling this parable for us or for all?” 42And the Lord said, “Who then is the **faithful** and wise manager, whom his master will set over his household, to give them their portion of food at the proper time? 43 **Blessed** is that servanti whom his master will find so doing when he comes.

Other commentaries how Canaan was cursed.

Ellicott's Commentary

> A servant of servants. That is, the most abject of slaves. This was fulfilled in the conquest of Canaau by Joshua

Pulpit Commentary

> A servant of servants. ... "a most base and vile servant" (Ainsworth);

The works of Jesus as a servant were blessed and became blessings to others.

Comment: I am downvoting your answer because, it doesn't appear you addressed the question: does the passage in Genesis point to the LORD coming to earth as a servant? Two other points, (1) a "servant" in the OT could be a honored position, like a steward. (2) The NT is explicit, Jesus became a curse for us (Galatians 3:13). IOW the complete(d) works of Christ are both blessing and curse, just as in Noah's words.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know your reasons.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is whether Noah's prophecy **also** points to God coming to earth as a servant. In other words, "Blessed be the LORD, the God of Shem, [who will come as a servant] and let Canaan (a servant of servants) serve Him."

Comment: Up-voted +1. I, also, cannot see that such a curse could be an allusion to the coming Lord.

Answer (score 0):

It is both a curse and prophecy, similar to the curses pronounced in prophetic literature.

According to [Coffman's Commentaries on the Bible](https://www.studylight.org/commentary/genesis/9-25.html):

> Significantly, the land of Canaan, historically, was never free and independent, but always dominated by the great world powers.